# Socket.io: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined why do i get this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Hello im building a collaborative whiteboard where you can join rooms. I took this example: https://gist.github.com/crtr0/2896891 to implement it in my Reactjs app.
Here is my code in my React component inside the constructor, thats where i get the error:

```
socket = io.connect();
var room = "abc123";
        this.socket.on('connect', function() {
          
            // Connected, let's sign-up for to receive messages for this room
            this.socket.emit('room', room);
         });
         
        this.socket.on('message', function(data) {
            console.log('Incoming message:', data);
         });
```

And this is my server.js code

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
room = "abc123";
io.on('connection', (socket)=> {
      console.log('User Online');
      socket.on('room', function(room) {
            socket.join(room);
        });
      socket.on('canvas-data', (data)=> {
            socket.broadcast.emit('canvas-data', data);
            
      })
      io.sockets.in(room).emit('message', 'what is going on, party people?');

// this message will NOT go to the client defined above
      io.sockets.in('foobar').emit('message', 'anyone in this room yet?');
})
```